# Removing Login Form in Wordpress after Registration Message

Tags: wordpress

I have built a job portal using wordpress. When someone has to post a job they have to register. When they click on registration it shows the Registration form with "username, email, first name, last name, display name" and register button. This is fine. When the register button is clicked it goes to a new page and shows message "Registration complete. Please check your email." And below that there is a login form . All I want to do is remove the login form from that page, I just want to display "Registration complete. Please check your email." and may be a link to the Home page. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add simple CSS to login enque scripts action for this. f.e. add this code to your theme's functions.php file.

```
add_action('login_enqueue_scripts','hideloginform');
function hideloginform(){
  if (isset($_GET["checkemail"]) and $_GET["checkemail"]=="registered" )
  echo '<style>#loginform {display:none !important}</style>';
}
```

Comment: Yeah done. How to do it for forget password page. When entered username or email it shows a message "check email for confirmation". At that time it shows a login form below. How to remove it.

Comment: if (isset($_GET["checkemail"]) and ($_GET["checkemail"]=="registered" or   $_GET["checkemail"]=="confirm"  ))
  echo '<style>#loginform {display:none !important}</style>';

Comment: It works but it shows the message 
ERROR: Cookies are blocked due to unexpected output. For help, please see this documentation or try the support forums.